# TabBarController: Going Tab-To-Tab - fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with two tabs (one TableViewController, one CollectionViewController). My app is crashing at times when I switch from one tab to another. It always crashes on the UITableViewController tab which is a simple Feed. The following breakpoint and info is shown:

```
0x498e44 <+68>:  bl     0x4efb9c                  ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x498e48 <+72>:  trap    // **This is the breakpoint
```

In the FeedView, I have the following and found another breakpoint in line 3:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell
    let currentItem = feedItems[indexPath.row]      // **Other error breakpoint occurs here

    let date = currentItem.createdAt
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)

    cell.userName?.text = currentItem.userName
    cell.itemName?.text = currentItem.itemName
    cell.timeStamp?.text = dateString

    // MARK: Setup image for cell
    cell.itemImage?.image = UIImage(named: "1.png")
    let image = currentItem.imageFile
    image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            cell.itemImage?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func getAndShowFeedItems() {                // I call this in ViewWillAppear

    feedItems.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let getFeedItems = FeedItem.query()
    getFeedItems!.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    getFeedItems!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                self.feedItems.append(object as! FeedItem)
                if self.feedItems.count == 35 {
                    break
                }
            }
        } else if error!.code ==  PFErrorCode.ErrorConnectionFailed.rawValue {
            self.showNetworkAlert()
            print("there's a networking problem")
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.resetUserDefaults()
            self.scrollToFirstRow()
    }
}
```

NOTE: I Am using Parse.com as my image store, and `venueImage` is a PFImage which doesn't allow me to unwrap the image the way you would a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in getAndShowFeedItems method. The server request can take more time. You are clean your array but don't reload table view. You have a crash if scroll table view before get items. You need change your code for this:

```
func getAndShowFeedItems() {                // I call this in ViewWillAppear

    feedItems.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    self.tableView.reloadData() // Need reload tableview when change it content
    let getFeedItems = FeedItem.query()
    getFeedItems!.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    getFeedItems!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                self.feedItems.append(object as! FeedItem)
                if self.feedItems.count == 35 {
                    break
                }
            }
        } else if error!.code ==  PFErrorCode.ErrorConnectionFailed.rawValue {
            self.showNetworkAlert()
            print("there's a networking problem")
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.resetUserDefaults()
            self.scrollToFirstRow()
    }
}
```

Also you have error in cellForRowAtIndexPath section. You can set wrong image when do scroll. Because table view will reusable invisible cell. So when your finish download image data cell can contain in wrong indexPath. You can rework your code like this.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell
        let currentItem = feedItems[indexPath.row]      // **Other error breakpoint occurs here

        let date = currentItem.createdAt
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)

        cell.userName?.text = currentItem.userName
        cell.itemName?.text = currentItem.itemName
        cell.timeStamp?.text = dateString

        // MARK: Setup image for cell
        if let image = UIImage(data: currentItem.imageData)
        {
            cell.itemImage?.image = image
            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        }else
        {
            cell.itemImage?.image = UIImage(named: "1.png")


            let image = currentItem.imageFile
            image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if !(error != nil) {
                    currentItem.imageData = imageData!
                    let index = feedItems.indexOfObject(currentItem)
                    if index != NSNotFound
                    {
                        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

The code can contains some inaccuracies I don't compiling it. Also you need add new property in class currentItem variable.

Comment: this worked - thank you for your solution! The load time has increased a bit but that is better than a crash. : )

Comment: You can show previous item before loading. You need move `feedItems.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` in block.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental design error here. You are trying to get data for a cell and set it with that block. But cell objects get re-used, and once a tableview goes offscreen, all cells might get disassociated from the table. What you need to do is fetch data, populate your model (i.e. array or dictionary), then post a block to the main thread that such and such a row needs to be refreshed. If that row is showing, you can get it from the tableview (via the array of visible cells). If its not showing, do nothing, when you are asked for the cell you'll have the data to populate it.

What I do in my apps is to have a separate method that takes a cell, its index, and updates the cell content. When I am asked for a new cell, I allocate one, then call this method. When I get some kind of internal notification that visible cell info might have changed, I call the same method (the point being you put the code that writes cell content in one place, not two).

EDIT: again, your problem is here:

```
(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil) {
        cell.itemImage?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

You are saving a reference to the "cell" which will in the future not be valid for the information you want to save in it, and the cell itself may have gotten deallocated.

As data comes in from the background, post a block to the main thread and save it in an array or dictionary. That same method can then update all visible cells. You don't need a NSNotification to do this - posting a block back on the main thread will do the trick nicely.

Comment: Good answer, but you no longer need to allocate cells for your table. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` now allocates a new cell of the proper type if none is available.

Comment: @Caleb not trying to be pedantic - I was on iPad to answer this not on Mac with all apis in front of me. This method you quote returns a cell - that is what I meant by "allocate". The core answer is - do not think you can access the temperate holder of your data (the "cell") at some point in the future. Its a temporal place holder to show your data.

Comment: The reason I pointed it out is that in older iOS versions (before iOS 6) you had to check the result of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and, if nil, you had to allocate a new cell yourself using `alloc` and `init`. So, like I said, good answer -- I just think that one part could cause some confusion if a reader happened to be looking at an older example.

Comment: Thanks @DavidH - so this is what I've gathered from your response please let me know if I understood correctly. You are suggesting that instead of setting my cell up in `cellForRow`.. that I write this into a separate method. When a new cell is needed (are you referring to `cellForRow..` in this case?), you run `deqeueReusable`... and then call the cell method? Also, for the internal notification of a visible cell change do you suggest I use `NSNotification`?